# ¿Cómo asignar foco a un input en Angular4?

Tags: angular4

Tengo una tabla con varios campos `<input>`y estoy necesitando simular un funcionamiento similar a excel, el cual me pueda mover entre los diferente input usando las flechas del teclado.

Al menos en cuanto al evento de detectar que se presiono la tecla lo tengo solucionado, los cuales son:

`(keydown.ArrowLeft)="function($event)" 
(keydown.ArrowRight)="function($event)"
(keydown.ArrowUp)="function($event)" 
(keydown.ArrowDown)="function($event)"`

los modelos, los manejo en un array multidimencional que bueno veré como calcular, el problema principal que tengo de momento es como cambiar el foco a un `<input>`especifico en typescript usando **Angular4**, no hace falta que la solución se corresponda con mi problema general, solo lo comente en que estaba intentando hacer, es suficiente que se pueda cambiar de foco.

Existe alguna directiva para esto o como se trabaja.

Saludos

Comment: Tienes que usar @ViewChildren o crear una directiva propia para esto

Comment: Por cierto, para simular un excel, donde sólo una celda está activa a la vez, puedes tener un único campo input, siendo el resto simples div con el texto. Al hacer click sobre una celda añades un input en esa celda y le das el foco en ese momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto tienes que usar `@ViewChild`

Te dejo un [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KvUmkuVBVbtL1AxFvU3F) funcionando para que lo veas en acción y abajo te explico mejor.

Tu html:

```
< (keydown.ArrowLeft)="function($event)" input #myInput />
< (keydown.ArrowLeft)="function($event)" input #myInput2 />
```

En el código deberías usar `@ViewChild` para encontrar el elemento HTML y luego aplicar acciones sobre el. (Si quieres leer mas sobre el tema https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Tu código quedaría así:

```
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("myInput") input: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild("myInput2") input2: ElementRef;

     function(event) {
          // tu logica para distinguir lo inputs

            this.input.nativeElement.focus() // hace focus sobre "myInput"
          }
    }
```

Ten presente que los elementos vinculados a @ViewChild, van a estar disponibles luego de que se dispare `ngAfterViewInit`.

Answer (score 0):

Probando varias alternativa termine implementando una Directiva

```
import {
    Directive,
    ElementRef,
    EventEmitter,
    Input,
    Inject,
    OnChanges,
    Renderer,
    ChangeDetectorRef
    } from '@angular/core';
import { element } from 'protractor';


@Directive({
    selector: '[focused]',
})
export class FocusedDirective {
    @Input() focused: boolean;


    constructor(
        @Inject(ElementRef) private element: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer,
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {}


    protected ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.focused) {
            this.element.nativeElement.focus();
            // this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.element.nativeElement, 'focus', []);
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

No la llame `focus` porque ya existía un evento con ese nombre para los input y no era la idea, en fin se usa así:

```
<input [focused]="attr.focus">
```

Lo que hay que controlar adicionalmente que mantenga solo 1 elemento con el atributo `focus` activo, sino tendrá foco el ultimo elemento seleccionado.